# How to disable Joomla k2 word limit for introtext

Tags: joomla-2.5, extensions, k2

The website I'm working on uses component K2 for Joomla 2.5. I need to display images from introtexts on category page with list of its articles but images don't appear because of word limit filter. How can I disable this only for K2 introtext? [not in global parameters of Joomla]

Comment: I am not sure k2 introtext limit make article image not display.
Did you set k2 article image display parameter to yes?
If you still want to disable introtext word limit in k2, Just set it to 0 in Parameters

Comment: Set the word limit to 0 in K2 configuration options.

Answer (score 1):

Disable html filter for introtext or just add "img" to exception list of introtext html filter.
You can find it in k2 settings